# Why can't i send a packet over to Radio in omnet?

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

Im facing this issue where i keep getting the error

> check_and_cast(): Cannot cast (inet::Packet*) to type 'inet::physicallayer::Signal *' -- in module (inet::physicallayer::Ieee80211Radio)

Im sending the packet using the following code:

```
    std::ostringstream str;
    Packet *payload = new Packet(str.str().c_str());
    payload->setTimestamp();
    L3Address destAddr = chooseDestAddr();
    emit(sentPkSignal, payload);
    socket.sendTo(payload, destAddr, destPort);
    numSent++;
```

The radio module that receives the packet runs the following code:

```
Signal *Radio::createSignal(Packet *packet) const
{
    encapsulate(packet);
    if (sendRawBytes) {
        auto rawPacket = new Packet(packet->getName(), packet->peekAllAsBytes());
        rawPacket->copyTags(*packet);
        delete packet;
        packet = rawPacket;
    }
    Signal *signal = check_and_cast<Signal *>(medium->transmitPacket(this, packet));
    ASSERT(signal->getDuration() != 0);
    return signal;
}
```

I am very very confused, as the function takes in an inet packet, and i am sending an inet packet, as it says in the error thrown. I am giving the function exactly what it wants. Is it probable that the function is wrong and you can't cast an inet packet to inet::physicallayer::signal? But the function comes from the inet framework which i don't think is wrong.

**EDIT**
I think its not actually going to Radio.cc? The error says Ieee80211Radio. I checked the source code but i cant find anything in there that does a casting. In fact, when i search the entire workspace, the only time `check_and_cast<Signal *>` appears is in Radio.cc

However, i also cant find out where Radio.cc is being called.

Comment: What does medium->transmitPacket return?

Comment: i cant find it. im using EV_INFO on the Radio.cc but its not printing. Im guessing it doesn't even go to Radio.cc since the error actually says Ieee80211Radio.